# Android UI testing: Monkey stuck in just a couple of Activities

Tags: android, testing, monkey

I've been trying to use Monkey to stress test the UI of my application.

What I've noticed is that the random key strokes are not able to traverse all the Activities of my application. It instead just keeps looping between a few of them.

Is there any strategy which you guys use to help Monkey traverse all the Activities?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am interested to find out how you did it

Answer (score 0):

AS per the documentation by default monkey should navigate between all activities and packages though this would happen in a random fashion. Hence the probability of some activities not being called cannot be ruled out

Hope you have not set any Constraints while running it. If not try listing the activities that are not being called in Constraints and then run the tool

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html

Comment: I dont think you answered the question.

Comment: Hmmm.. may be . I was just asking a question back for which i did not get a reply from the person who posted this...btw what is your question here?

Comment: No, I have not set any constraints. Hmmm...maybe I need to add CATEGORY_MONKEY to my activities or use the DEFAULT category in the constraint.

Comment: Maybe you should download the source-code and take a look at the random number generator and see if you can improve it.